# XPath - extract value from parent with highest node value

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xpath-2.0

This is my XML snippet

```
    <FinancialSummary>
            <SummaryDate format="YYYYMMDD">20111231</SummaryDate>
            <Revenue currency="EUR">1249164523</Revenue>
    </FinancialSummary>
    <FinancialSummary>
            <SummaryDate format="YYYYMMDD">20101231</SummaryDate>
            <Revenue currency="EUR">1242344523</Revenue>
    </FinancialSummary>
    <FinancialSummary>
            <SummaryDate format="YYYYMMDD">20091231</SummaryDate>
            <Revenue currency="EUR">324900932</Revenue>
    </FinancialSummary>
```

Im trying to extract the node content from the revenue node within the financialsummary tag with the highest numeric summarydate value.

```
/FinancialSummary[SummaryDate = '20111231']/Revenue
```

this xpath returns correct = 1249164523

```
max(/FinancialSummary/SummaryDate)
```

this xpath returns correct = 20111231

however when i try to combine both nothing is returned

```
/FinancialSummary[SummaryDate = max(/FinancialSummary/SummaryDate)]/Revenue
```

Is there something I am missing? What is the solution to this puzzle?

extra information: I tried contains instead of '=' but no luck with that

Comment: There seems to me something missing here. Your first expression begins with a `/`, and there can be only one root to an XML document. Your last expression includes this slash too, meaning there's only one thing it can return, the first and only document root node's Revenue elements, but only if it satisfies your predicate. Likewise, your middle expression seems impossible to return the correct data as well. Are you sure this is the whole context?

Comment: @Abel, I agree with what you're saying, but the terminology is confusing. There can only be one "root", but this refers to the root node (`/`), not the outermost element. Thus "root node's Revenue elements" doesn't make sense... The root node's only children are FinancialSummary elements. You apparently mean the outermost element's Revenue element children.

Comment: @LarsH: there can be only one root, that we agree on. In the example XML there are three "roots", that's not valid. The predicate `[SummaryDate = max(/FinancialSummary/SummaryDate)]` selects something, but there's nothing to select: there's only one root, no choice there. I agree that my wording is ambiguous. I meant to say _"the expression finds all Revenue elements that are children of the root node (FinancialSummary) provided that the root node satisfies the predicate"_.

Comment: @Abel, there is discrepancy, or at least muddiness, between the XML and XPath specs on whether "root" can mean an element or not (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node). To avoid confusion, it's better to call an element that has no element parent something like "document element", "top-level element" or "outermost element". Of these, "document element" is problematic when the XML fragment is not a well-formed document.

Comment: The full xpath is in fact longer. I did not write the full xpath because I don't want to show too much company information and I did not want to confuse you because i just posted a snippet from the xml. It seems lik I kinda failed at the 'not confusing' part though, it seemed a good idea when i was posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this expression answers your question :

```
FinancialSummary[SummaryDate = max(./parent::*/FinancialSummary/SummaryDate)]/Revenue
```

The context in your predicate is FinancialSummary. You have to get up in th tree to get the others. This expression can return several nodes, if some have the same date.

**EDIT** :

I remove the first slash. *Consequence* : You have to be in the right context (parent of `FinancialSummary`) to launch this XPath query.

Comment: His expression started with `/`, this goes up to the root of the document. To start at the current node, he should've written `./` instead. But your expression can still be a solution, as it searches any first child of the document.

Comment: Note that `./parent::*/` is equivalent to `../`.

Answer (score 3):

This works (notice `//` instead of `/` and the shift to the context parent in the predicate):

```
//FinancialSummary[SummaryDate=max(../FinancialSummary/SummaryDate)]/Revenue
```

However, it would be *even better* (i.e. stricter and more efficient) to provide a direct path to `FinancialSummary` that's based on your document's actual structure.

Problems in your sample XML and proposed solution:

- You have provided an XML sample that is not well-formed
- Your expression begins at the root (`/`), but your actual document probably does not contain a root `FinancialSummary` (since it appears that those elements are further down in the tree)

Comment: +1 That's precisely what I meant (see my comment). This looks more like a suitable solution. Indeed, `//` is code-smell and slow on most processors and should be removed by the OP in his solution with a direct path.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the reason it doesn't work when the two XPaths are combined is that in the first case, you are comparing SummaryDate to a string, `'20111231'`, but in the second case, you are comparing SummaryDate to a number, `max(...)`.

To test this, try

```
/FinancialSummary[SummaryDate =
     string(max(/FinancialSummary/SummaryDate))]/Revenue
```

Also, I agree with @Able and @lwburk that this would be less confusing if you would not try to treat an ill-formed XML sample (multiple top-level elements) as if it were an actual XML document (addressed using "/FinancialSummary/..."). I guess you're trying to be brief and communicate only what you think is relevant to the problem. But it's obviously not right, and it sets off all sorts of alarms. Clarity about this would help.